# Why this function is undefined at $x=0$ and $x=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

According to my understanding, the domain of $\sqrt{x}$ is $x \ge 0$. If this is correct, shouldn't the domain of the function 
$$\frac{1}{(x^2-5x)^{1/4}}$$
be $x \le 0$ or $x\ge 5$ instead of $x<0$ or $x>5$? What am I getting wrong? (the answer is $x<0$ or $x>5$).

Comment: denominator cannot be zero

Comment: Can’t read it. Please take the effort to get familiar with MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac1{g(x)}}$$

we need also that $$g(x)\neq 0$$

Thus in this case we have

$$x^2-5x>0 \implies x(x-5)>0 \implies x <0 \quad x>5$$

Comment: thanks. I was dumb for a second :)

Comment: Gimusi.Huh.You are fast.

Comment: @user1917231 don't worry about that, I'm dumb too very often :)

Comment: @PeterSzilas It was not so difficult here! :)